# Hide view inside fragment before onAttach() method called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to hide view inside my fragment, when `onAttach()` method is not called. I know that view will not be hided before this method, but I want to know is any way to realize that?

To be more specific, my problem is that I want to hide some views in fragment(B), when I am in other fragment(A) and after `onAttach()` method called in fragment B, views must be hided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. First of all, it should be mentioned that fragments are used in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and, I am not sure does it right or not, but my fragment are called in following way

```
companion object {

    internal var addressQFragment = AddressQFragment()

    fun newInstance(): AddressQFragment {
        return addressQFragment
    }
}
```

So, all my variables can be changed before `onAttach()` function called. Using this I first changed my flag and when view is created it will work with this flag and hide necessary views. If there is more correct way, I am waiting your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the Fragment lifecyle in the offical doc https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments. Fragment's views are drawn first in the `onCreateView()` lifecycle i.e after the `onAttach()`, there you can initialise the view and set it as invisible. So when your Fragment B is loaded, the user will not be able to see those views and it will be hidden.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but my case is that I call hiding function before `onCreateView()` is called. So, I need to views be hidden after `onAttach()` is called with condition that I call hidden function before it.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling your hiding function before the `onCreateView()`? The view will be drawn in the UI only after the `onCreateView()` and it will not be visible before it. So in your `onCreateView` you can call the hiding function that is the best approach.

Comment: Because my condition is completed before the fragment created

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility to gone/invisible from xml file and when you need to show that then programatically set visibility to visible.